# Identification of a pattern based on given features in time-series data

Tags: time-series, mathematical-statistics, gaussian-process, pattern-recognition

I am working with electricity time-series data collected at 15 minutes intervals. I am looking for a procedure/theory to find the pattern/sequence in the time-series data based on given **features**.
As I am working with electricity time-series data and solving the problem of solar PV identification from these data, the given features would be:

**1. There is a fall in electricity consumption during 7am-8am as generation from the PV starts.**

**2. There is a rise in electricity consumption during 5pm-6pm as generation from the PV ends.**

See below figure to understand the above two features.

[image]

I have gone through the literature for the same. I got the following:

1. **Gaussian prior**: This works with considering the **prior knowledge** and **evidence**. In this case, the prior knowledge would be above two features, and the evidence would be the time-series data.
2. **Cross-correlation**: This basically looks for the relation between two patterns.
3. **Various ML techniques**: The different ML techniques can be applied such as clustering, HMM, DTW etc.

I am not looking to solve this problem with option 3. Can anyone guide me with the option 1 as it looks more relevant to my problem. I cannot understand how Gaussian prior can fit into the problem. Summarily, I want to utilize above two features as the prior knowledge and use the given data(electricity time-series) as the evidence to prove that the solar PV panel is present or not.

Comment: I am a little confused about your usage of notions like feature, prior, or evidence. Could you please state precisely what your given data is and what you want to achieve? Is it, maybe, that you want to learn an algorithm that can assign to each of your electricity time series a binary value stating whether a PV is present?

Comment: Prior knowledge is the two features described in the question, and evidence is my electricity consumption data (12 months data). I want to identify whether the given pattern (per day consumption data) is having PV panel or not. For that, with the Gaussian prior, the prior knowledge and evidence is required. Gaussian prior is what I am looking as one of the solutions of my problem. You can suggest other statistical approaches as well.